# JavaScript: Error when destructuring an array of objects when the array is empty

Tags: javascript, destructuring

**What is the cleanest way of getting around this scenario?**

Considering I have an array of objects:

```
let originalArray = [{
  personName: 'Ben'
}];
```

I can destructure like this:

```
const [{
  personName: name
}] = originalArray;

console.log(name); // "Ben"
```

However, if `originalArray` is empty...

```
let originalArray = [];

const [{
  personName: name
}] = originalArray;
```

I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property `personName` of 'undefined' or 'null'
```

I've found some articles/docs explaining how to handle errors when destructuring just an object, but not if it's an array of objects, and the array is empty.

Comment: You could just do `if(originalArray.length > 0 )` before deconstructing

Comment: What kind of behavior would you expect in this case except for an error though?

Comment: Why not just use default values or null guards?

Comment: I'm looking for the cleanest and most modern way of getting around this scenario, please answer with an example. Sorry I should have made that clear - question has been updated.

Comment: what do you mean by handle errors ? You could make a check before destructing. To see if the array is empty or not. Otherwise you will get this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set default values for undefined properties

```
const [{
  personName: name = ''
} = {}] = originalArray;

console.log(name); // ""
```

Comment: I'm not sure setting default values on an array is the right thing... The array is probably empty for a reason. Personally I'd check the length of the array first and then only deconstruct it if it contains elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a default value

```js
var [{ personName: name = 'default' } = {}] = [{ personName: 'Ben' }];
console.log(name);

var [{ personName: name = 'default' } = {}] = [];
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the array like this. So it will be an empty array of object  by default. Otherwise will throw that error.

```
let originalArray = [{}];
```

You can also declare a default value if you know how many properties you will have.

```
let originalArray = [];

const [{
 personName: name = 'ben',
 personAge: age = '23'
} = {}] = originalArray;

console.log(name); // "Ben"
console.log(age); // "23"
```